# How to write SQL script to find rows in any tables of a SQL Server database that have a string column which value is equal to a keyword?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Environment: Windows, SQL Server 2008

For example, my database has Table1, Table2, Table3... TableN, each table has Column1, Column2, Column3...ColumnN. Simply, they're all string column.

I want to find rows, no matter from which table, which have a column's value is 'Key' no matter which column.

How to write a script to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the FindMyData_String stored proc here: [Search all columns in all the tables in a database for a specific value](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2) to get you started

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE PROC SearchAllTables
(
    @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
SET @SearchStr = 'Wound'

CREATE TABLE #Results (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO #Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM #Results
END
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, but this will only work on similar structured table

```
DECLARE @Table nvarchar(100), @Column nvarchar(100)
DECLARE @SQLStringBuilder nvarchar(MAX) = ''
DECLARE MY_CURSOR Cursor
FOR SELECT sysobjects.name, syscolumns.name
    FROM sysobjects 
    JOIN syscolumns ON sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id
    JOIN systypes ON syscolumns.xtype=systypes.xtype
   WHERE sysobjects.xtype='U' and  systypes.name <> 'sysname' and systypes.name = 'nvarchar' 
ORDER BY sysobjects.name,syscolumns.colid 
Open MY_CURSOR 

Fetch NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Table, @Column
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @SQLStringBuilder = @SQLStringBuilder +  ' SELECT ''' + @Table + ''' as TableName, ''' + @Column +  ''' as ColumnName, * FROM ' + @Table + ' WHERE ' + @Column+ ' = ''Key'' UNION ALL'

Fetch NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @Table, @Column

END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
SET @SQLStringBuilder = SUBSTRING(@SQLStringBuilder, 0, LEN(@SQLStringBuilder)-9)
EXEC(@SQLStringBuilder)
```